# How to Setup SSL for Camel Route using the embedded Active MQ Broker in a service mix?

Tags: ssl, apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-servicemix

I am trying to use blueprint XML for the setup

My Blueprint XML looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint
    xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0
      http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
      <route>
        <from uri="file:activemq/input"/>
        <to uri="file:activemq/output"/>

        <setBody>
          <simple>
            FileMovedEvent(file: ${file:name}, timestamp: ${date:now:hh:MM:ss.SSS})
          </simple>
        </setBody>
        <to uri="activemqs:queue:Main.Queue.Vibhav"/> 
      </route>
    </camelContext>

    <bean id="activemqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="ssl://localhost:61616" /> 
        <property name="keyStore" value="file:C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/apache-servicemix-4.5.3/etc/myclient.ks"/>
        <property name="keyStorePassword" value="test123"/>
        <property name="trustStore" value = "file:C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/apache-servicemix-4.5.3/etc/myclient.ts"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
        <property name="maxConnections" value="8" />
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="activemqConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

      <bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="transacted" value="false"/>
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
      </bean>

      <bean id="activemqs" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig"/>
      </bean>


</blueprint>
```

Note: In the broker I have already added the ssl context and the ssl connectors, also the plugin which has ssl certificate with the jaas realm.

Comment: Did you answer your own question?  That's what it looks like.

Comment: We are getting a null pointer exception every time camel is trying to connect to ActiveMQ. It looks like that it is not connecting to the embedded active mq component when I follow the stacktrace. We are using the example route with ActiveMQ on the serviceMix getting started guide. We added a camel component that uses ActiveMQSslConnection. 

I am also unsure how camel is finding the "activemq" component without specifying the component in the xml.

Comment: I have a lot of questions.  I'll just start a couple. Is the embedded broker configured with the SSL transport on port 61616?  And, where do you see a component named "activemq"?  In an error message?  I see the "activemqs" component definition and use.

Comment: Pasting the full stack trace that you're getting might help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by setting the trust store password in the connection factory properties.